# Order between @ControllerAdvice and custom Aspect

Tags: java, spring, aop

## tl;dr

How can I define the order of custom aspects and the `@ControllerAdvice`?

## Detailed description

I want to decorate various methods (like normal REST-Calls or a `@JmsListener`) with MDC information on controller-level.

The idea is: I, as a developer, don't have to think about the MDC data in my controller-methods.
I want extra MDC-information (e.g. the userId) and I can be sure, that information will be correctly removed.

### my aspect

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MdcSugar {

  @Pointcut("within(@MdcAwareController *)") // <- MdcAwareController is my annotation
  public void beanAnnotatedWithMdcAwareController() {
    // this pointcut identifies beans annotated with @MdcAwareController
  }

  @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
  public void publicMethod() {
    // this pointcut identifies public methods
  }

  @Pointcut("publicMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithMdcAwareController()")
  public void publicMethodInsideMdcAwareController() {
    // this pointcut identifies public methods on beans annotated with @MdcAwareController
  }

  @Before("publicMethodInsideMdcAwareController()")
  public void addMdcSugar(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    log.info("Entered");
    MDC.put("test", "test");
  }

  @After("publicMethodInsideMdcAwareController()")
  public void removeMdcSugar() {
    log.info("Leaved");
    MDC.clear();
  }
}
```

### example controller

```java
@RestController
@MdcAwareController // <- my annotation
public class SomeController {

   // doesn't matter if the method is a JmsListener or something else
   @GetMapping("/{id}")
   public String get(@PathVariable String id) {
      MDC.put("id", id);
      log.info("Got request");
      throw new RuntimeException("too bad ...");
   }
}
```

### ControllerAdvice

```java
@ControllerAdvice
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class GeneralExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

  // some others cases with different handlers

  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  protected ResponseEntity<HttpErrorResponseBody> handleUncaught(RuntimeException e) {
    log.error("Uncaught exception occurred", e);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e.toString(), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Now I have a problem when a exception occurs. My aspect will always clear the MDC-context **before** the exception-handler jumps in. Log example:

> Entered
> [test=test][id=someString] Got request
> [test=test][id=someString] Leaved
> Uncaught exception occurred

But I want something like this:

> Entered
> [test=test][id=someString] Got request
> [test=test][id=someString] Uncaught exception occurred
> [test=test][id=someString] Leaved

I already tried to place `@Order()` on `MdcSugar` and `GeneralExceptionHandler`, but with no affect.

Comment: you can't. AOP affects/defines target bean, controller advices are responsible for the processing of request - MVC explicitly called them ServletInvocableHandlerMethod#invokeAndHandle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the world is so easy - I only need to clear the MDC-data at the beginning.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class MdcSugar {

  @Pointcut("within(@MdcAwareController *)") // <- MdcAwareController is my annotation
  public void beanAnnotatedWithMdcAwareController() {
    // this pointcut identifies beans annotated with @MdcAwareController
  }

  @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
  public void publicMethod() {
    // this pointcut identifies public methods
  }

  @Pointcut("publicMethod() && beanAnnotatedWithMdcAwareController()")
  public void publicMethodInsideMdcAwareController() {
    // this pointcut identifies public methods on beans annotated with @MdcAwareController
  }

  @Before("publicMethodInsideMdcAwareController()")
  public void addMdcSugar(@Nullable JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    MDC.clear();
    log.info("Entered");
    MDC.put("test", "test");
  }
}
```

Comment: it will print "test" to all logs of current thread till next invocation of addMdcSugar. Is it ok for you? Does request logs clash with each other?

Comment: @cynepnaxa yes, it is perfect for me. All controllers have their own thread-pools, the threads will not be used in other places. There is a chance, that when I forgot the `@MdcAwareController`, that this class/methods will have unwanted mdc-data. I'm currently fine with it, but I'm open for new ideas.